# Convert XML to Array using attributes as conditional

Tags: arrays, xml, attributes

I need to add to an existing array, converting XML to PHP, but I need to do so based on the attributes of a particular field.

The array uses: `$details = simplexml_load_string($result);`

The source xml looks like this:

`<MemoList><Memo Type="Sponsorship" SubType="Pet Sponsorship">Sponsored by Tom Jones</Memo></MemoList>`

There are many different memos in the xml string, but I only want to post the ones with "Sponsorship" as the type attribute.

I tried with this and a number of different combinations without any luck.

```
foreach($details->MemoList->Memo as $memo) {
foreach($memo->attributes() as $type => $memovalue) {
if($type == 'Sponsorship') {
echo ".$memovalue.";
}
}
}
```

`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
 <?php
    $data='<MemoList><Memo Type="Sponsorship" SubType="none">sponsored by Tom jones</Memo></MemoList>';
    $details=simplexml_load_string($data);


    foreach($details->Memo as $memo) {
    if($memo['Type'] == 'Sponsorship') {
            echo "$memo";
                }   
            }

    ?>
```